# Allocation of incomplete type error in QT c++

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to implement my very first project of a mediaplayer using QT c ++ , currently i have this issue where it says "error: allocation of incomplete type 'Ui::About_display'"

.h

```
#ifndef PLAYERFRAME_H
#define PLAYERFRAME_H

#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
class About_display;
}

class About_display : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit About_display(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~About_display();

private:
    Ui::About_display *ui;
};


#endif // PLAYERFRAME_H
```

.cpp

```
include "playerframe.h"
#include "ui_about_display.h"

About_display::About_display(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::About_display) ..> where error occurs 
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

About_display::~About_display()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Thank you for the help !!

Comment: You have declared (in your header) and used this pointer of type `Ui::About_display` in your source file, but you haven't defined.

Comment: Adds #include with generated header of About_display form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring `class Ui::About_display;` but defining `class About_display`. Make sure the `class` definition is in the `Ui` namespace:

```
#ifndef PLAYERFRAME_H
#define PLAYERFRAME_H

#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {

class About_display : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit About_display(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~About_display();

private:
    About_display *ui;   // `Ui::` not needed
};

} // namespace Ui

#endif // PLAYERFRAME_H
```

And also in the `.cpp` file:

```
#include "playerframe.h"
#include "ui_about_display.h"

namespace Ui {

About_display::About_display(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new About_display)         // `Ui::` not needed
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

About_display::~About_display()
{
    delete ui;
}

} // namespace Ui
```

Note: While placing the class definition and implementation of the member functions in the `Ui` namespace will make it compile, you are recursively creating a new `About_display` for every `About_display` you create. I suspect you should use the `QDialog`s constructor and remove the `About_display *ui;` member.

Header:

```
#ifndef PLAYERFRAME_H
#define PLAYERFRAME_H

#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {

class About_display : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    using QDialog::QDialog;   // add the QDialog constructors
};

#endif
```

The member functions you've defined in your original code are already covered by `QDialog` so with what you've shown, you don't need to implement them in the `.cpp` file.

Comment: However it seems to give me this error "about_display.cpp:8:7: error: member access into incomplete type 'Ui::About_display'
about_display.h:7:7: note: forward declaration of 'Ui::About_display'" i tried to understand and solve it i cant see why its wrong

Comment: @Anjelo What code do you have in `about_display.cpp`? There shouldn't be a forward declaration of `About_display` in the `about_display.cpp` translation unit.

Comment: what i did was as i understood due to recursive creation of about_display i included header file with Qdialog constructors and kept the .cpp file as its but somehow its giving me errors and im confused right now to be honest

Comment: @Anjelo I think you missed the namespace part of the answer. "_You are declaring `class Ui::About_display;` but defining `class About_display`_". The class definition must be in the `Ui` namespace - and so must the implementation of any member functions (if you have any). If you look at the last header in the answer, that should really be all you need since it covers the member functions you had in your original code.

Comment: oh thank you so much i understand what i have done wrong , however after all corrections it says again " no member named 'setupUi' in 'Ui::About_display'"

Comment: @Anjelo I must say I'm a bit inexperienced when it comes to Qt. `ui` seems to be something that should be generated by the Qt forms designer if I read [this](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/designer-using-a-ui-file.html) correctly. I don't have the tools to build a full blown example myself right now. If you post a question with a minimal example Qt app, I may be able to reproduce it later when I get the chance (or someone else surely will).

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace Ui
{
class About_display; // declares a class Ui::About_display
} // however, namespace closes!

class About_display // so this is *another* class ::About_display in global namespace!
    : public QDialog
{
   // ...
};
```

You need to include the entire class definition in the namespace:

```
namespace Ui
{

class About_display // NOW it is in namespace UI
    : public QDialog
{
   // ...
};

} // only here the namespace closes
```

You need to declare all the members inside the class; however you don't have to provide full definitions; these you can provide outside as in the following example:

```
namespace Ui
{
class Demo
{
    void demo(); // only declaration
};
}

// full definition – usually in .cpp file
void Ui::Demo::demo()
{
}
```

However recursively creating a child dialog will recurse endlessly until at some point you run out of stack (-> stack overflow...):

```
Ui::About_display::About_display(QWidget* parent)
    : ui(new About_display()) // <- will create a child on its own, too
                              // that one will create yet another child,
                              // that one again, and again, and again...
```

Why would you need that child at all?